# Including a non-text file in compiled binary

Tags: c, embedded-resource

Let's say I was creating an application that uses some font library that is linked into the program, and it has an API function such as:

```
void load_font(char* path);
```

where path is the relative path to a font-file (*.ttf or *.otf).

However, I would like to include a few fonts as part of the installation (as part of the binary). Is there a way for me to include the contents of these files in the binary, then pass some sort of pointer to the location of these files to the library function? Would I have to modify the library to change where it reads the font-file?

The other approach I was considering is bundle these files in with the installation, and detect the location within the binary itself, which could also work, but then I run into some issues with finding the right location of the binary (eg, could be run from another directory, or linked from somewhere else).

What's the best approach (if any) for something like this?

Comment: Typically one writes a short program (a few lines of Python, say) to convert the file into C, as a declaration like `static uint8_t font[] = { 0x00, 0x12...`, and then include that. You might also try something like bin2elf.

Comment: Are you looking for a utility like `xxd` that can make a C header file out of the hex of another file?

Comment: Hmm, I think this is probably my best bet. I'm just seeing if there's some kind of compilation tool that would make the process easy to embed a resource. In this method, I'll have to edit and rebuild the library myself to be able to pass it the binary data directly rather than the path to the file.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how portable this is, but `gcc` provides a mechanism to store arbitrary binary blobs in object files, and reference them.

Suppose I have a data file "test.txt". Embed it in an object file like this:

```
ld -r -b binary -o test.o test.txt
```

This creates the symbols `_binary_test_txt_start` and `_binary_test_txt_end` which can be used in a C module like this:

```
extern char _binary_test_txt_start[];                                                                                          
extern char _binary_test_txt_end[];                                                                                                                                                                                                             
int main (int argc, char **argv)                                                                                           
  {                                                                                                                       
  int i, size =  _binary_test_txt_end - _binary_test_txt_start;                                                           
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++)                                                                                                
    putc (_binary_test_txt_start[i], stdout);                                                                             
  putc ('\n', stdout);  
  ...                                                                                                  
  }
```

I've only used this for text, but I would imagine other data would work, too. I confess that I have no idea whether there is a limit on the amount of data that can be included -- tens of kB at least seems fine. I've used this mechanism on Linux and Windows Subsystem of Linux. There seems to be some variation between `gcc` versions about how the binary symbols are named, but the versions I've tried produce

```
_binary_[filename]_[extension]_start
```

On Windows there is a resource API for loading fonts, images, etc., from object files into Win32 API objects, which may be more appropriate if you're working on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Of course. [Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html#compiled-in-resources) does it as well as other frameworks. An image or whatever file is after all just some binary data at its core. You can read files as binary stream, store it (usually as a byte array) and then you can convert it back as long as you also store it's file signature (the part of the file that actually tells you what the file is supposed to represent). All this is language-independent hence it doesn't matter if it's C, C++, Python etc.

A word of caution though - embedding such resources in your binary leads to increased size of that binary but more importantly the resources are stuck in there so if you want to change even a single one you will have to recompile the whole thing.

Comment: If you append a `.zip` file to the executable, it avoids many of the problems with other embed methods.

Answer (score 1):

It is much better to keep the fonts as external resources (better yet to go through a general-purpose framework like fontconfig to locate them).

All fonts have encoding limitations, many fonts have bugs, unless you have absolute control and foreknowledge of the text your app is going to display embedding the font files is painting yourself in a corner.

It is much simpler for everyone involved to replace external fonts (or, better, to configure another font set) whenever there is need to process new unicode codepoints rather than change the whole binary, and potentially void previous QA. Think new currency symbols, trendy emoticons, use in new geographical region, compliance with a customer graphical charter, special accessibility fonts, there is always a need to change font files later.

Lastly fonts are protected by the law and have specific licensing (even gratis fonts). If you embed those in your software, you need to check with a lawyer the legal aspects are ok. Embedding is such a corner case the license under which you received the font files may not cover it.